# MongoDB Query Timeout

Tags: mongodb, optimization

I have the following collection `geo` with the following indexes:

```
> db.geo.getIndexes();
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "geospatial.geo"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "checkin_id" : -1
        },
        "name" : "checkin_id_-1",
        "ns" : "geospatial.geo"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "loc" : "2dsphere",
            "created_at" : -1,
            "user_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "loc_2dsphere_created_at_-1_user_id_1",
        "ns" : "geospatial.geo",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "created_at" : -1
        },
        "name" : "created_at_-1",
        "ns" : "geospatial.geo",
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 31557600
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "loc" : "2dsphere",
            "created_at" : 1
        },
        "name" : "loc_2dsphere_created_at_1",
        "ns" : "geospatial.geo",
        "background" : true,
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
    }
]
```

But running this query:

```
db.geo.find(
   {
     loc:
       { $near :
          {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ -73.9667, 40.78 ] },
            $minDistance: 1000,
            $maxDistance: 5000
          }
       },
      created_at: {  $gte : new ISODate("2017-06-23T00:00:00Z") }
   }
)
```

OR

```
db.geo.distinct(
    "user_id",
     {
     loc:
       { $near :
          {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ -73.9667, 40.78 ] },
            $maxDistance: 16093.4
          }
       },
     created_at: {  $gte : new ISODate("2017-06-23T00:00:00Z") }
 }

).length
```

It just times out, and never processes. Any ideas what I am missing here with an index? There is are 74m+ documents in this collection.

Sample Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59740de9e5bfa822388b4567"),
    "checkin_id" : XXXXX,
    "user_id" : XXXX,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-07-23T02:44:36.000Z"),
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -88.2165, 
            42.3718
        ]
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Here is the `executionStats` results:

```
{
    "cursor" : "S2NearCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 57740,
    "nscannedObjects" : 77737,
    "nscanned" : 200823,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 123823,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 300660,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 1514,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "allPlans" : [
        {
            "cursor" : "S2NearCursor",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 57740,
            "nscannedObjects" : 77737,
            "nscanned" : 200823,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {

            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "S2NearCursor",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 101,
            "nscannedObjects" : 46086,
            "nscanned" : 99837,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {

            }
        }
    ],
    "server" : "ut-geobrain-01:27017",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "GEO_NEAR_2DSPHERE",
        "works" : 258567,
        "yields" : 0,
        "unyields" : 0,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 57740,
        "needTime" : 0,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "children" : [ ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running your query with a `.explain("executionStats")` to try and figure out what's going on?

Comment: **Multiple** `"2dsphere"` indexes are not a good idea. Aggregate `$geoNear` for example does not support the presence of any more than **one** geospatial index on the collection, as there is actually no way to specify which field is being used for the geospatial query in that operation. So you should reconsider the multiple indexes and come up with **one** that suits your most common needs.

Comment: I'm a little confused here about the results that you're showing both here and in your comment on the existing answer, as both of those queries appear to have completed in under two seconds (1514 ms in your question, .1483 ms in your comment), unless I'm not remembering correctly how to interpret those results.  Are you just running these commands from the shell and not getting anything back?  Also, what version of MongoDB are you running?

Answer (score 2):

Set the processing time of the query through `maxTimeMS`

```
db.geo.find(...).maxTimeMS(1000 * 1000 * 1000);
```

Comment: Yes - but that's no good, the query should be faster via the index?

Comment: ```{
 "cursor" : "S2NearCursor",
 "isMultiKey" : false,
 "n" : 57643,
 "nscannedObjects" : 77609,
 "nscanned" : 200493,
 "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 123606,
 "nscannedAllPlans" : 300166,
 "scanAndOrder" : false,
 "indexOnly" : false,
 "nYields" : 0,
 "nChunkSkips" : 0,
 "millis" : 1483,
 "indexBounds" : {

 },
 "server" : "ut-geobrain-01:27017",
 "filterSet" : false
}```

Comment: It scanned 200493 out of 74M. Are the points packed together ? Can you try a different query ?